# Trouble installing xmpppy python library and recognizing modules

Tags: python, xmpp, spotify, xmpppy

My overall project involves me attempting to use python 3.4 to update my Cisco Jabber status with my the current song I'm playing in Spotify.  This is on win 7 for my work laptop.

I was first attempting to get the feel for a good python library that will allow me to change my Jabber status, and I read http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/ here that xmpppy might be what I'm looking for.  Pip wasn't recognizing xmpppy, so I downloaded the library from that website and used `python.exe setup.py install` in the unzipped folder (from the download) to install.  I felt the install went successfully.

However, attempting to `import xmpp` (the folder that was installed in site-packages was called just xmpp), leaves this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    import xmpp
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xmpppy-0.5.0rc1-py3.4.egg\xmpp\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
import simplexml,protocol,debug,auth,transports,roster,dispatcher,features,browser,filetransfer,commands
ImportError: No module named 'debug'
```

In the xmpp folder, I can see simplexml.py, protocol.py, debug.py, etc, but the shell is not loading them with the import.

Is there something more I should be using in my import statement to ensure the modules are loaded?  Do I perhaps have them located in the wrong place?

And a bonus question, is there a better library for the job?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `from xmpp import debug` ? Or you could `import <module>; print <module>.__file__` to see if the library is in the right python version not in python2.7?

Since only `import debug` means you have a library called debug, but seems your problem is trying to import `debug` from `xmpp` module.

In addition, to the question for a better library

it depends on your requirement of your project, there are other library like `Wokkel, twisted, tornado, Sleekxmpp` might able to do the work. However, you might need to spend more time to understand their architecture, `xmpppy` could gives you a simple implementation without spend too much time on understanding their structure.

Hope it helps.